# Why does zip --exclude only exclude files in the folder but not the folder itself?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell-script, zip

I have the following command run in the `bash` shell which excludes the files in the folder `scripts/`. I tried the answer in [Zip command for excluding directories and files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898627/zip-command-for-excluding-directories-and-files) but unfortunately it did not work in my case.

```
zip_cmd="zip -r '${output_zip}' '${parent_folder}'/* \
  --exclude '${parent_folder}'/.git/* \
  --exclude '${parent_folder}'/scripts/* \
  --exclude '${parent_folder}'/$(basename "$0") \
"
```

But I can't for the life of me, for several days now, figure out how to exclude the folder as well. The `scripts` folder still always shows up in the resulting zip file. I tried

```
--exclude '${parent_folder}'/scripts/"
--exclude '${parent_folder}'/scripts"
--exclude '${parent_folder}'/scripts*"
--exclude '${parent_folder}'/scripts\*"
--exclude '${parent_folder}'/scripts/\*"
--exclude '${parent_folder}'/scripts/*"
```

Here's more context of how the script is executed in case if this helps understand my problem better. For some reason the `.vscode` and `.git` folders are completely excluded but it's just the same syntax. What gives?

```
zip_cmd="zip -r '${output_zip}' '${parent_folder}'/* \
  --exclude '${parent_folder}'/.vscode/* \
  --exclude '${parent_folder}'/.git/* \
  --exclude '${parent_folder}'/temp/* \
  --exclude '${parent_folder}'/scripts/* \
  --exclude '${parent_folder}'/*.template.* \
  --exclude '${parent_folder}'/$(basename "$0") \
"

mapfile -t exclude_pycache < <(find "${parent_folder}" -type d -name "__pycache__")
mapfile -t exclude_executables < <(find "${parent_folder}/voxconvert-executable" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name "${voxconvert_version}")
exclude_paths=("${exclude_executables[@]}" "${exclude_pycache[@]}")

for path in "${exclude_paths[@]}"; do
  zip_cmd+=" --exclude \"$path/*\""
done

eval "$zip_cmd"

echo "Created zip file: $(pwd)/${output_zip}"
```

**UPDATE: Response to** @[**Kamil Maciorowski**](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski)

The reason I'm using a string and doing `eval` instead of using an array and `"${zip_cmd[@]}"` is because the excludes don't work when using an array, hence using a string and doing `eval` was the only solution. Here's the attempt I had previously but the extracted paths placed into `exclude_paths` were still always included in the zip output.

```
seven_zip_cmd=("7z" "a" "-r" "${output}" "${parent_folder}"/*)

exclude_patterns=(
  "${parent_folder}/.vscode/*"
  "${parent_folder}/.git/*"
  "${parent_folder}/temp/*"
  "${parent_folder}/*.sh"
  "${parent_folder}/$(basename "$0")"
)

mapfile -t exclude_pycache < <(find "${parent_folder}" -type d -name "__pycache__")
mapfile -t exclude_executables < <(find "${parent_folder}/voxconvert-executable" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name "${voxconvert_version}")
exclude_paths=("${exclude_executables[@]}" "${exclude_pycache[@]}")

for path in "${exclude_paths[@]}"; do
  # Ensure proper path formatting and add it to the exclude patterns array
  path=$(realpath "$path" --relative-to="${parent_folder}")
  exclude_patterns+=("${path}/*")
done

# Construct the exclude string within the loop
for pattern in "${exclude_patterns[@]}"; do
  seven_zip_cmd+=("-x!${pattern}")
done

# Execute the 7z command
"${seven_zip_cmd[@]}"

echo "Created 7z file: $(pwd)/${output}"
```

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem, but in general building a command string to  `eval` it later *safely and reliably* is hard; you are asking for trouble. You use arrays in other places, so your shell supports arrays (BTW, you should explicitly state what your shell is, don't let us guess), so there is no reason for `zip_cmd` not to be an array. Make it an array; then you run it as `"${zip_cmd[@]}"`, not with `eval`. See [*How can we run a command stored in a variable?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/108618)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski hello thank you for your reponse. sorry i'm using `bash` shell and I edited the question to explain why `"${zip_cmd[@]}"` was not possible in my case.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Hi i tried again and asked chat gpt to convert the script to using an array instead of the eval and tested it out and it works. so i'm wondering if this anomaly with the `scripts` folder not being excluded was indeed caused by the unreliability of `eval`. But thank you very much for your time and advice!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. Turns out it is possible to run as array instead of a string with `eval`

```
zip_cmd=("zip" "-r" "${output_zip}" "${parent_folder}"/* \
  "--exclude" "${parent_folder}/.vscode/*" \
  "--exclude" "${parent_folder}/.git/*" \
  "--exclude" "${parent_folder}/temp/*" \
  "--exclude" "${parent_folder}/**/useful/*" \
  "--exclude" "${parent_folder}/scripts/*" \
  "--exclude" "${parent_folder}/*.template.*" \
  "--exclude" "${parent_folder}/$(basename "$0")"
)

mapfile -t exclude_pycache < <(find "${parent_folder}" -type d -name "__pycache__")
mapfile -t exclude_executables < <(find "${parent_folder}/voxconvert-executable" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name "${voxconvert_version}")
exclude_paths=("${exclude_executables[@]}" "${exclude_pycache[@]}")

for path in "${exclude_paths[@]}"; do
  zip_cmd+=("--exclude" "$path/*")
done

"${zip_cmd[@]}"

echo "Created zip file: $(pwd)/${output_zip}"
```

And now it properly excludes the scripts folder. So probably this anomaly was caused by the unreliability of using a string and eval as pointed out by @[Kamil Maciorowski](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski).